# Awarded more than 15 badges in last 30 minutes - best way of merging?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, stack-overflow

I've been awarded more than 15 badges on SO in last 30 minutes, but my rep has not changed at all. Anyone else seeing this. Is there some recalc going on, and shouldn't that change my rep?

**Edit** It turns out my original SO account got merged with my current one, so I got the badges and the rep for the original.

I opened the second account (i.e. the current Neil Butterworth one) for several reasons

- I wanted a new name, specifically my real name
- I didn't realise you could rename accounts - I still think renaming is a bad feature of SO
- I wanted to present a slightly different personality

So I opened up two accounts, which lays me open to charges of sock-puppetry (charges I've laid against others). However, I've never used the first account after I opened the second.

What I didn't want was the questions, answers, rep and badges transferred automatically from the first account to the second. If SO management wants to do this, can I suggest that they email the account holder to ask if they want a merge or a deletion before going ahead in cases like this? If no response, they should default to deletion, not merge.

Comment: I'd like to add another upvote for your edit. Definitely ask before merging.

Comment: @ChrisF Well, don't be shy - do upvote it!

Comment: I said *another* - I'd already voted on your original question

Answer (score 6):

You had some alternate accounts that were merged with your primary account.

Comment: Well to be accurate I had one alternate account, because at the time I didn't realise you could rename them - I never used it after opening my current one.

Comment: Is it polite to merge accounts without asking? Maybe he was using two accounts intentionally (which is permitted as far as I know, if you don't upvote yourself).

Comment: Why in the world would you want two accounts?

Comment: @Josh In my case because I wanted to be known by my real name, and didn't realise I could change it.

Comment: @Jeff If the badges got merged, shouldn't the rep have been added too?

Comment: Ah, that would explain it. Add the rep too. +1

Comment: @Jeff Please see edit to my question.

Comment: @Neil - I assume you'll get the rep when a recalc is done. Badges are awarded by jobs that run periodically.

Comment: @Josh: ask or answer questions anonymously, start over from scratch, ask a question that you don't want your potential employers or people googling your name to see, and these are just examples. As long as you don't do anything stupid (such as upvoting your own posts) there isn't anything wrong with not wanting to sign everything you do with your real name.