# Earning badges all at once

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I just took a look at the **Recent Badges** column and the high frequency of occurrence of a username caught my attention:

[image]

I then visit the links of these badges to see how this user (jrharshath) earn all these badges at once. It turns out that these questions are quite old and he should have earned them a long time ago.

**Famous Question**:
https://stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question?userid=2119053

[image: Famous Question]

**Notable Question**:
https://stackoverflow.com/badges/27/notable-question?userid=2119053

[image: Notable Question]

**Good Question**:
https://stackoverflow.com/badges/21/good-question?userid=2119053

[image: Good Question]

Why did he earn all these badges at the same time?

Comment: Maybe a timed suspension expired?

Comment: Most likely two accounts got merged into 1

Comment: @иɪvэЖєvɪɴ Do you mean something like [Awarded more than 15 badges in last 30 minutes - best way of merging?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47731/awarded-more-than-15-badges-in-last-30-minutes-best-way-of-merging)

Comment: Yep, looks like the same situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was an established user that was merged, some badges are re-awarded as part of that process, so that's what you're seeing here.  It's rare that it happens to someone with so many badges, but it does happen on occasion depending on the specific merge.  We typically would prefer that older account as the "master", meaning fewer moves...but not in this case.